# ASP.NET Core Windows Authentication and Application Roles

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to create a fairly simple intranet application that will use Active Directory for authentication, and will use the AspNetRoles table to check if the user is in a certain application role. This app is just an in-house lottery where some users can create events/contests that other users can then submit an entry to the contest. I'm thinking of starting out with 2 basic roles:

- Administrator - Can perform CRUD operations on "Event" or
  "Contest" entities
- Contestant - Can perform GET operations on
  "Contest" entities, and can create new "Entry" entities.

Here's where I'm stuck: I've got Windows Authentication working in the sense that from a controller, I can do a `User.Identity.Name` and see my domain login name. Furthermore, I can verify that an account belongs to a domain group by doing `User.IsInRole("Domain Users")`. If I want to avoid creating new AD groups for each role in my application (let's say design changes down the road require additional roles), how can I use Authorization on controllers to check against Application Roles?

Here's an example controller I want to use:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Contestant")]
public class EventTypesController : Controller
{
    private IRaffleRepository _repository;
    private ILogger<EventTypesController> _logger;

    public EventTypesController(IRaffleRepository repository, ILogger<EventTypesController> logger)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet("")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var results = _repository.GetAllEventTypes();
            return Ok(Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<EventTypeViewModel>>(results));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Failed to get all event types: {ex}");
            return BadRequest("Error occurred");
        }
    }
}
```

In my Startup.cs, in ConfigureServices, I'm wiring up Identity as follows:

```cs
services.AddIdentity<RaffleUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<RaffleContext>();
```

My RaffleUser class is really just the default implementation of IdentityUser:

```cs
public class RaffleUser : IdentityUser
{

}
```

My ApplicationRole class is also just the default implementation of IdentityRole. I also tried seeding some data in a seed class:

```cs
if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Administrator"))
{
    var adminRole = new ApplicationRole()
    {
        Name = "Administrator"
    };
    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(adminRole);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

if (await _userManager.FindByNameAsync("jmoor") == null)
{
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "DOMAIN\\jmoor");
        if (principal != null)
        {
            var user = new RaffleUser()
            {
                Email = principal.EmailAddress,
                UserName = principal.SamAccountName
            };

            await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            var adminRole = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync("Administrator");
            if (adminRole != null)
            {
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, adminRole.Name);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The data makes it to the tables, but it just seems like at the controller level, I need to convert the authenticated user to an IdentityUser. Do I need some middleware class to do this for me? Would that be the best way to make authorization reusable on all controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a DefaultChallangeScheme to use Windows authentication. This is how i do, but if someone has a better solution i am all ears :)

I use the following setup in my current application.

```cs
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SecurityDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});
```

Then i put in my application claims in a transformer.

```cs
services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
```

I hope this will get you in the right direction.

Comment: oops. Didnt see the date of your question. I hope you solved it long ago.

Comment: I haven't tested all my controllers thoroughly, but it does look like this accomplishes what I was looking for. I'll post the alternative I came up with, which is also using the newer policy-based authorization.

Comment: Also use 'options.DefaultScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;'

Answer (score 2):

First, I ended up creating a custom ClaimsTransformer that returns a ClaimsPrincipal populated with UserClaims and RoleClaims (after refactoring my app, I decided to go with policy-based authorization, and the access claim can be added at either the role or user level):

```cs
public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsTransformationContext context)
{
    var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;
    var userName = identity.Name;
    if (userName != null)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByLoginAsync("ActiveDirectory", userName);
        if (user != null)
        {
            identity.AddClaims(await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user));
            var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            identity.AddClaims(await GetRoleClaims(roles));
        }
    }
    return context.Principal;
}

private async Task<List<Claim>> GetRoleClaims(IList<string> roles)
{
    List<Claim> allRoleClaims = new List<Claim>();
    foreach (var role in roles)
    {
        var rmRole = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(role);
        var claimsToAdd = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(rmRole);
        allRoleClaims.AddRange(claimsToAdd);
    }
    return allRoleClaims;
}
```

I wired that up in the Startup.cs:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformer, Services.ClaimsTransformer>();
```

I also went with Policy-based authorization:

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Administrator", policy => policy.RequireClaim("AccessLevel", "Administrator"));
    options.AddPolicy("Project Manager", policy => policy.RequireClaim("AccessLevel", "Project Manager"));
});
```

So, users or roles can have a claim set with a name of "AccessLevel" and a value specified. To finish everything off, I also created a custom UserManager that just populates the User object with additional details from ActiveDirectory during a CreateAsync.